# Usage of "specific number(s) of ~"

Tags: word-usage

Let's say you have a sentence:

- *These presents are only for the people who have 2, 4 or 6 coins.*

How can I paraphrase the sentence using "specific number(s)"?

(1)"Presents for the people who have specific number of coins"?

(2)"Presents for the people who have specific numbers of coins"?

(3) Both above are wrong and here is the answer!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your context is a bit "unusual", so I suggest you give the audience / readers something to help them see what you're getting at. For example, *These presents are only for people who have **exactly** one of the specified numbers of coins*. I'd prefer ***specified*** rather than ***specific*** there, because you're effectively "defeating" the normal strong association between ***specific*** and *a **single** example or value*. Or perhaps it would amount to the same thing if you just said *...only for people who have **an even number of coins***.

Comment: **A** noun = an example of a noun. 2, 4, and 6 are all "an example of a number,"

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence (2) is correct because there are several valid 'specific numbers'.

"...for the people who have a specific number of coins" would be correct if there were only one valid number.

Also, I think the accurate paraphrase would have to include 'are':

Presents **are** for the people who have specific numbers of coins.

Comment: "...for the people who have a specific number of coins" is also correct in this instance. It is an example of the distributive singular. Each qualifying person has one of the numbers specified (2, 4 or 6).

Answer (score 0):

As @Greybeard suggested, you need an indefinite article, namely "a".

"Presents for the people who have **a** specific number of coins"

Answer (score -1):

It is always "**a number of**" rather than anarthrous "**number of**" (1). "Numbers" would imply multiple numbers, such as a 4, a 7 and a 2.

Comment: The pluralisation of singular members of multiple sets is common. 'Show your wife you love her by buying her flowers.' **or** 'Show your wives you love them by buying them flowers.'